# Images disappearing when scrolling in listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a new app in Flutter, but when there are some images that are taller than the screen, the image disappears.

I'm using the latest version of Flutter/Dart.
I tried adding cacheExtent to ListView, but nothing changed.
Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.18362.356], locale it-IT)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    super.build(context);
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11740.jpg', width: width, height: width, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        Image.network('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11740.jpg', width: width, height: width, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        Image.network('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11740.jpg', width: width, height: width, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
...
      ],
    );
  }
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKGt5.gif)

Comment: Add some screenshots. the code works fine. I even loaded a very long image. it's working as expected.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Issue on GitHub on flutter repo. The bug hasn't yet fixed, follow the issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42339)

Answer (score 2):

Use the cacheExtent value to 9999 inside Listview, Gridview and CustomScrollView

```
ListView.builder(
    cacheExtent: 9999,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:
1 > Wrap the images widgets in another widget (container, for example)
2 > Use ListView.builder and Wrap up listView in a container or some Widget you prefer.

Comment: So try replace ListView per ListTile,

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `BoxFit.fill` That Will Load Your image According to your Phone Size
OR 
Give only Width To `double.infinity`
and leave Height Parameter empty

Comment: I need the image to be square

Comment: you can empty height parameter and then apply Box.fill it will work

Comment: And Wrap Your ListView in container and Give Static height and Width

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   child: ListView(
       children: Widget[
          Container(
            width: 300,
            height:300,
            child: Image(
               image: NetworkImage("your networkd image here"),
               fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
            )
         )
      ]
   )
)
    );
```

Do it As Much as you like :)

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context){
*add my code here*
}

Comment: I know how to develop in Flutter 