# Why are list items glitching and partially disappearing when scrolling in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

When I scroll in a list view (or list view alternative), some textual parts of the items in the list disappear. They usually reappear as I continue scrolling. I've recorded a video showcasing my issue and uploaded it to YouTube: https://youtu.be/cMg9qD0fXcY

(I tried scrolling and expected object persistence - the items should continue appearing the same as I scroll, just translated across the vertical axis.)

Debugging notes:

- Initially I thought it's related to the ListView Widget from Flutter because it doesn't happen with GridView (as far as I see)
- I tried setting the cacheExtent as was suggested in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258152/images-disappearing-when-scrolling-in-listview-flutter)
- I tried changing the ListView to a SliverList with SliverChildBuilderDelegate (what you see in the video) or with SliverChildListDelegate.fixed and in both cases the glitch still happens
- Tried changing to a PagedListView from the infinite_scroll_pagination package, glitch still happens
  (of course, in all these cases I adapted the code maximally to achieve the same UX as I had with the ListView)

Comment: Did you define the key for each item?

Comment: Yes, still happens. Information even sometimes switches between widgets within the row so it seems a bug with Flutter itself and some rendering function

Answer (score 0):

This was due to using the deprecated FlutterWebRenderer. When I updated my index.html following [this documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization#upgrading-an-older-project) then it seems to be fixed!